# How to switch from php v8.0 to v8.1

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I am using an ubuntu digitalocean droplet as a web application server. I have 2 active applications that require `php8.0` and above but I want to deploy a third application that requires `php8.1`.

I have installed php8.1 and edited my nginx configuration for each application to use`php8.1`. Ran `php -v` command and the active version is still `php8.0`

How can I switch to `php8.1`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default PHP 8.0:

```bash
php -v
```

Run installed PHP 8.1:

```bash
/usr/bin/php8.1 -v
```

You can switch active version by:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Output

```bash
There are 2 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php8.1   70        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php8.1 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in manual mode
```